# Xamarin Plugin.FirebasePushNotification causes app to go into break mode

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

The Xamarin Plugin.FirebasePushNotification causes my application to go into break mode, it was working but after I sent 2 notifcations through the console then anytime I tried to run the app it would go into break mode and say an An unhandled exception occurred, it says your app has entered break state but there is no to code to show because all the threads were executing external code.

This is the code that is causing it in MainApplication.cs:

```
public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

            //If debug you should reset the token each time.
            #if DEBUG
                        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
            #else

                     FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
            #endif

        //Handle notification when app is closed here
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
                {

                };
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am unable to post a demo but that is where the problem is occurring in the above code as when i take it out, the app works fine